# Deleting terminal services CALs

Tags: terminal-server, licensing, cal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

We are using volume licensed CALs and I need to remove *some* of the installed CALs, but as far as I can tell, there is no procedure to do this.

Comment: I have to ask; why would you need to remove TS CALs? The license server is separate from the session server, multiple session servers can connect to a single license server.

Answer (score 1):

Just checked one of mine, I couldn't see anything obvious, I'd give the MS CAL phone number a call and ask them.